# What complications (e.g., random seed issues, library calls) are there when using a forked process in R?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, fork

Suppose in R, use parallel to create a forked process that does some work:

```
library(parallel)

my_seed = 1

x0 = .Random.seed
id = mcparallel({
  set.seed(my_seed)
  require(abind) 
  x = abind(x=rnorm(5),y=rnorm(5)) 
  })
res = mccollect(id)
x1 = .Random.seed
```

I'm setting the random seed, loading a library, and creating a variable. When this exits, in the parent process 'x' is not defined, the `{abind}` namespace is not loaded, and the RNG state is still the same as it was:

```
exists("x")
# [1] FALSE
identical(x0, x1)
# [1] TRUE
isNamespaceLoaded("abind")
# [1] FALSE
```

- Do I have it right that the state of the parent is not affected by things that happen in the child fork?
- Are there any ways that contamination can take place?
- Where can I read more about the dangers of forked processes, in an R context?

Comment: Already tried `parallel::mclapply` and played withe the `mc.set.seed=` argument?

Comment: Yes, I have done that.

Comment: Gives me reproducible multithread results with `mc.set.seed=FALSE`, but that addresses only one point of your questions.

Comment: Yes, I know how to get reproducible random numbers - I'm more interested in the possibility that something might change in the parent process that I'm not suspecting.

Comment: `parallel::mclapply` warns me if one of the cores yielded errors and other processes might be compromised, not sure how that can be generalized, though.